# PHP Adjacency Data to Nested Array

Tags: php, arrays

I am having array as follows:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [question_id] => 1
            [question_title] => Q1
            [child_question_id] => NULL 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [question_id] => 2
            [question_title] => Q2
            [child_question_id] => NULL
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [question_id] => 3
            [question_title] => Q3
            [child_question_id] => 4
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [question_id] => 3
            [question_title] => Q3
            [child_question_id] => 5
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [question_id] => 4
            [question_title] => Q4
            [child_question_id] => NULL
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [question_id] => 5
            [question_title] => Q5
            [child_question_id] => NULL
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [question_id] => 6
            [question_title] => Q6
            [child_question_id] => NULL
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [question_id] => 7
            [question_title] => Q7
            [child_question_id] => 6
        )

)
```

And using PHP I am expecting result as:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [question_id] => 1
            [question_title] => Q1
            [child_question_id] => NULL 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [question_id] => 2
            [question_title] => Q2
            [child_question_id] => NULL
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [question_id] => 3
            [question_title] => Q3
            [children] => array(
               [0] => Array
               (
                  [question_id] => 4
                  [question_title] => Q4
               )

              [1] => Array
              (
                  [question_id] => 5
                  [question_title] => Q5
               )

              )
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [question_id] => 7
            [question_title] => Q7
            [children] => array(
              [0] => Array
               (
                    [question_id] => 6
                    [question_title] => Q6
               )
              )
        )

)
```

I tried to build final array using following logic:

1. Traversing array to collect child ids and child data
2. Traversing array again and match items child id with child array
   formed earlier, if found then create children array

Could you please help me out to create better solution?

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean something like that?

```
$i = 0;
$new = array();
$unsetter = array();
foreach($array as $val)
{
    $new[$i] = array();
    foreach($val as $key => $data)
    {
        if(($key == 'child_question_id') && (!is_null($data)))
        {
            $new[$i]['children'] = array();
            $new[$i]['children']['question_id'] = $data;
            $new[$i]['children']['question_title'] = $array[$data]['question_title'];
            $unsetter[] = $data; 


        } else {
            $new[$i][$key] = $data;
        }
    }
    $i++;
}
foreach($unsetter as $uns)
{
        unset($new[$uns]);
}
$new = array_values($new);
var_dump($new);
```

This will output

```
array (size=5)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'question_id' => int 1
      'question_title' => string 'Q1' (length=2)
      'child_question_id' => null
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      'question_id' => int 2
      'question_title' => string 'Q2' (length=2)
      'child_question_id' => null
  2 => 
    array (size=3)
      'question_id' => int 3
      'question_title' => string 'Q3' (length=2)
      'children' => 
        array (size=2)
          'question_id' => int 4
          'question_title' => string 'Q4' (length=2)
  3 => 
    array (size=3)
      'question_id' => int 3
      'question_title' => string 'Q3' (length=2)
      'children' => 
        array (size=2)
          'question_id' => int 5
          'question_title' => string 'Q5' (length=2)
  4 => 
    array (size=3)
      'question_id' => int 7
      'question_title' => string 'Q7' (length=2)
      'children' => 
        array (size=2)
          'question_id' => int 6
          'question_title' => string 'Q6' (length=2)
```

#### [Live Demo](http://ideone.com/uffjS4)